# Navigation Controller issue with ViewPager

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using [this Library](https://github.com/StefanLage/SLPagingView) for creating ViewPager effect like twitter. 
 
My storyBoard look like this :
[image]

So the problem if I try to push a view from one of the pager view (the red, yellow ... controller) it won't navigate because `self.navigationController` is null ?

This is my navigation code :

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"bundle:nil];
    PostReaderViewController *postReaderView =
    (PostReaderViewController *)
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postReaderView"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:postReaderView animated:YES];
```

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert `UINavigationController` into your storyboard and then connect those colourful view controllers as their `rootViewController`.

Hierarchy in the storyboard is like:

```
The View Pager - UINavigationController -> red view controller
The View Pager - UINavigationController -> green view controller
...
```

In short;
there must be (4, in this case) `UINavigationController`s between the view pager and those view controllers

Comment: Any other solution to do somethingLike this : `- UINavigationController  - The View Pager-> red view controller` That means using one navigation controllers

Comment: I' will check this solution because I work's but not optimal Also the Library have been updated and now you can simply push by using `self.parentController.navigationController`